# Tkinter - How to create a GUI that updates text in the same window?

Tags: python, tkinter

Base code

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import keyboard

animals = ["cat", 'dog', 'mouse', 'giraffe', 'elephant', 'alligator', 'cow', 'horse', 'duck']

root = Tk()

while True:
    keyboard.wait('0')
    an_animal = random.choice(animals)
    #Tkinter stuff
```

I would like a window that displays a random animal from the above list when the keyboard key `0` is pressed. Would like this done in the same window as opposed to opening a new window.

What widgets do I need to use? How do I do this?

Comment: You should work through a tkinter tutorial. You'll learn about relying on `mainloop` instead of providing your own infinite loop, and using keyboard bindings instead of the `keyboard` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BryanOakley said, you need to use bindings when using tkinter instead of relying on the `keyboard` module

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import random


def update_labels_text(event):
    # Generate the new text
    new_text = random.choice(animals)
    # Change the label's text
    label.config(text=new_text)

animals = ("cat", "dog", "mouse", "giraffe", "elephant", "alligator", "cow",
           "horse", "duck")

# Create the window
root = tk.Tk()

# Create the label:
label = tk.Label(root, text=random.choice(animals))
# Show the label on the screen:
label.pack(fill="both")

# Call `update_labels_text` when the user presses 0
root.bind("0", update_labels_text)

# Enter tkinter's main loop
root.mainloop()
```

It binds to the user pressing `0` and changes the label's text to a random element of that list.

**EDIT:**
Making it work even if the window is out of focus:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import random
import keyboard
from threading import Thread

label_needs_new_text = True

def listen_keyboard():
    global label_needs_new_text
    while True:
        keyboard.wait("0")
        label_needs_new_text = True

def update_labels_text_loop():
    global label_needs_new_text
    if label_needs_new_text:
        # Change the label's text
        label.config(text=random.choice(animals))
        label_needs_new_text = False
    # Call `update_labels_text_loop` again in 100ms
    label.after(100, update_labels_text_loop)


animals = ("cat", "dog", "mouse", "giraffe", "elephant", "alligator", "cow",
           "horse", "duck")

# Create the window
root = tk.Tk()

# Create the label and show it on the screen
label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack(fill="both")

# Start the new thread:
thread = Thread(target=listen_keyboard, daemon=True)
thread.start()

update_labels_text_loop()

# Enter tkinter's main loop
root.mainloop()
```

It uses a `while True` loop with the `keyboard` library to listen for the user keyboard presses. When the user presses `0`, it setts a global variable named `label_needs_new_text` to `True`.

There is a second loop that is made using `tkinter` `.after` scripts. It looks for when `label_needs_new_text` is `True` and changes the label's text.

It uses 2 loops because `tkinter` isn't fully thread safe, so `tkinter` can crash if you call it from another thread.

Comment: I noticed the keyboard only works if the GUI window is in focus. Is there anyway to make this work when the window is out of focus as well?

Comment: @Wellwoah That is bad practice most of the time. Most of the time you want the user to know what's receiving the keyboard presses. I don't think `tkinter` supports that anyways.

Comment: @Wellwoah: if part of your requirement is that the code works when it doesn't have focus, that needs to be included in the question.

Comment: @BryanOakley Fair enough. I will remember that for the future, I apologize that it did not occur to me.

Comment: @TheLizzard The reasoning makes complete sense but this program is for personal use and the out of focus element is a requirement. Is there another GUI framework you know of that would support this?

Comment: @Wellwoah I only know how to use `tkinter`. I will try to find another solution.

Comment: @Wellwoah Try it now. I updated my answer. Now it should work (first time I use the `keyboard` module :D)

Comment: works fantastic thankyou! also working through your code helped clear up a couple misconceptions I had on how tkinter works so thanks for that as well!

Comment: @Wellwoah Glad to have helped. I am a bit surprised that it worked myself :D